# Groovy closure return of value to variable

Tags: groovy, closures

Very basic question but I cannot find an answer:

I have the below code in a file `g.groovy`, and it functions in printing output:

```
#! /usr/env/groovy

def matchFiles = { match ->
    new File(".").eachFile() {
        if (it.name =~ match) {
           println it
       }
    }
}
```

`matchFiles('.groovy')` prints `./g.groovy` to screen.

But I want to capture the output of the closure in a variable and use it elsewhere, e.g.

```
def fileMatches = matchFiles('.groovy')
```

but cannot figure this out.

Tried changing `println it` to `return it` and then running

```
def fileMatches = matchFiles('.groovy')
fileMatches.println { it }
```

but this prints something like `g$_run_closure2@4b168fa9`

Any help is much appreciated, sorry for any incorrect nomenclature, very new to Groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the name `matchFiles` I assume you want to return all matched files

so, you have to define an array result variable where you are going to store each matched file

and then return this `result` variable after `eachFile{...}` closure

```
def matchFiles = { match ->
    def result=[]
    new File(".").eachFile {
        if (it.name =~ match) {
            result.add(it)
        }
    }
    return result
}

println matchFiles(/.*/)
```